# Prevent users from running programs and scripts from the folder download using GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

i want to prevent users from running programs and scripts from the folder
download. 
Can someone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Scripts from the folder means??  Can be more clear

Comment: @TechieGossip Prevent  users to run a program and a script in the folder Download

Comment: What you want script?? Den only why from or to download folder?? It's wasn't clear again

Comment: @TechieGossip lets say if in folder Download, there is a program and a script, i want to prevent users from running  the program and the script using GPO

Comment: @TechieGossip it isn't so hard. ASG want to prevent that a file that was downloaded and stored in the Download folder can be executed at its current location. ASG wants to make sure the file is moved out of the Download folder prior to its execution.

Comment: Is Group Policy required? Is it on just one machine or more?

Comment: Also, keep in mind, that if a user browses the web, presses a downloadlink, and instead of choosing save, they choose run, the file is downloaded to their Temporary Internet Files, and run from that location. Depending on what browser they are using, this location varies.

Comment: @LPChip yes Group Policy is required as it involves many users and more that one machine.  Yes but i understand but i want to prevent users from executing any program and scripts contained in the Download folder only . Thanks

Comment: Only for pc he can deny traverse and execute file in security option of that particular user.. in group policy I think we can make try on script .Bat file.. but u know consumption of network bandwidth come to picture

Comment: @TechieGossip..lets try with one machine...can i use a GPO to deny traverse and execute file for any users using only one machine? where should i configure this policy?

Comment: @TechieGossip  If i use AppLocker, will it solve my issue?

Comment: @ASG What does your research indicate?

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to block the execution of firefox using AppLock through GPO but not the execution of the script file using PowerShell

Comment: @ASG - If you want to block the execution of a script through powershell, then prevent powershell from being executed by non-Administrators.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks i will try it and revert back to you if i get any issues